# MongoDB limit to number of sparse indexes

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query

I have a specific need to have a particularly large number of sparse indexes in a MongoDB collection. The number would likely be in the low thousands. The documents stored would each use only a relatively small number of indexes, around 10 - 30 each on average. However, the documents are highly varied, and will require different sets of indexes each.

I cannot find any documentation as to the likely effects of having > 1000 sparse indexes on a collection. Space is not a concern. My specific concern is the impact on save time and query set-up. Will MongoDB get bogged down with this large overhead?

I will run my own benchmarks, but I'd like to know a) if someone knows of some official guidelines on this and b) has any experience with this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a namespace limitation (total number of indexes, collections, etc.) that you might run into, but that can be lifted with --nssize: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Using+a+Large+Number+of+Collections

The inserts will have some overhead added, but it should "fail fast" once it realizes the document you're inserting doesn't need to be added to most of the indexes. Disclaimer: I haven't tried benchmarking nearly as many as you're considering. I'm interested to see if it will work.

One thing to keep in mind is that you'll not be able to use more than one index per query without using $or, which is a current limitation in mongodb. http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexing+Advice+and+FAQ#IndexingAdviceandFAQ-Oneindexperquery.

Comment: you mean there is no way to simultaneously search multiple partial indexed fields?

Comment: Well, you can, using $or -- what are your query patterns going to look like?

Comment: Also, you can search more than one, but it will pick one index to use and scan for the rest (which obviously isn't desirable if you're looking for fast results).

Comment: Thank, I read the reference. What is bizarre is I tested this on an 8-field query, and the speed killed PostgreSQL and SQL Server. Yet, as you said, a query can only use one index at a time.

Comment: To best illustrate what I want, picture storing the data of various types of vehicles (cars, bikes, trucks) in a collection with a sparse index defined for each parameter of each vehicle type. Then, a query could look something like: "give me all documents where cylinders is between 5 and 7 or null AND price is < 20000 AND engineCapacity is between 2000 and 2500 or null AND weight is between 1500 and 2000 or null".

Comment: Not surprised that it's still faster than the others. Mongo does a really good job at collection scans/index scans if they fit in RAM. Make sure you benchmark with a production-level amount of data to set realistic expectations.

Comment: Yeah, multiple range queries are a weak point in mongo (even with indexes on all of the fields in the ranges), from my experience. You might vote for this (yet unplanned) issue, which would probably improve performance for your use case. https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-785

Comment: SERVER-785 is for partial indexes (also useful), but that's not what I need.

Comment: You could define a sparse index with multiple keys by filtering out values that don't exist--at least, that's my understanding. That way, you could index cylinders, price, enginecapacity, weight, but if those values don't exist, the document wouldn't be indexed. Of course, you might have to create several such indexes to match your queries, but it was just an idea (and not really an option yet).

Comment: I thought sparse indexes only allow one key (field) at a time? My idea was to add one index per field.

Comment: Ps. are the terms "key" and "field" interchangeable in MongoDB parlance?

Comment: Right (sparse indexes are for only one field), but that issue will effectively allow you to build indexes for more than one field, sparsely (partially). About key and field, I think they are interchangeable in many contexts, but in my opinion, a field is a key/value pair, where a key is just a key.

Comment: AFAIK, a partial index, technically, is an index over a predefined range, which isn't the same as sparse.

Comment: A sparse index is a special case of a partial index because it's over the range of documents that have values.

Comment: Well, I see what you mean, but technically a partial index requires a filter to be partial (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_index). MongoDB is unique in that it has no schema, so one could perhaps argue that in such a case, your statement is correct :)

Answer (score 1):

Until this is implemented in the server, you could run your OR query twice - once for each field and merge the results in the client.

For example if you had objects:

```
{_id: 123, foo: 12}
{_id: 124, bar: 13}
{_id: 124, foo: 12, bar: 15}
```

You could have one sparse index `{foo:1, _id:1}` and another `{bar:1, _id:1}` and do queries like `find({foo:12}, {_id:1})` and `find({bar:13}, {_id:1})` and then OR or AND the object Ids in the client. You could then retrieve the full objects for just those matching IDs.

Note: by retrieving just the `_id` field in the find queries, Mongo can return the results from the index and doesn't need to unpack any BSON to give the results making this very quick.